# Using greedy algorithm to solve MAX CUT

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I'm trying to use the greedy algorithm to get a max-cut.

I'm a bit confused on what you do. I'm trying to follow this.

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15854-f05/www/scribe/lec02.ps.

So I get that you go in ordering of vertices. So you choose $v_{1} \in S$ and then go onto $v_{2}$. However, do you choose $v_{2} \in \overline{S}$. Then, how do you choose $v_{3}$ to be in. Is it $v_{3} \in S$ since we have two in $S$ and three in $\overline{S}$ so we put the next vertex into the set with the least amount of edges in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose the set that gives you the biggest increase in the number of  cut edges.  With $v_1 \in S$ and $v_2 \in \overline{S}$, putting $v_3$ in $S$ increases the number by $1$ (namely $v_2 v_3$) while putting it in $\overline{S}$ would leave it the same (because 
$v_1 v_3$ is not an edge).